# Boost C++ - assertion failed: body_.file_.is_open() and body limit exceeded

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast

I'm new to Boost and trying to add a POST request to one of the client example. But I failed to read a `http::quest<http::file_body>` request on the server side.

```
Assertion failed: body_.file_.is_open(), file D:\Boost C++ Projects\AsioServre\include\boost _1_72_0\boost\beast\http\impl\file_body_win32.hpp, line 184
```

I read the Boost code in this *file_body_win32.hpp* file, it just simply tells me the file is open. How come? And the werid thing is if I change `content_type: "text/plain"` to `content_type: "image/jpeg"` (body opens an image), then the assertion will be passed, but with body limit exceeded error.

**Client Side:**

```
std::string path = "C:\\Users\\Jinx\\Desktop\\Damn\\test.txt";
body.open(path.c_str(), boost::beast::file_mode::scan, ec);
req_to.version(version);
req_to.method(http::verb::post);
req_to.target(target);
req_to.set(http::field::host, host);
req_to.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
req_to.set(http::field::content_type, "text/plain");
req_to.content_length(body.size());
req_to.keep_alive(req_.keep_alive());
req_to.body() = std::move(body);
req_to.prepare_payload();

http::async_write(stream_, req_to, beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_write, shared_from_this()));
```

On the server side, I have no idea what type of buffer I should use. I've tried a multi buffer, it didn't work either.

**Server Side:**

```
beast::tcp_stream stream_;
beast::flat_buffer buffer_; 
std::shared_ptr<std::string const> doc_root_;
http::request<http::file_body> req_from;

http::async_read(stream_, buffer_, req_from, beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
```

According to the [http::file_body](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__http__file_body.html) document:

> When serializing, the implementation will read the file and present those octets as the body content.

How can the file opened by the server?

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, before calling `http::async_read(stream_, buffer_, req_from, beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_read, shared_from_this()));` you must open the file, to which the body content should be written to.

To do so do the following:

```
// Add an error_code, which lives as long as the async operation
boost::beast::error_code ec;

// Then before reading the content of the request do
req_from.body().open("file.jpeg", boost::beast::file_mode::write, ec);
http::async_read(stream_, buffer_, req_from, beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
```